# How can I strengthen my user account creation script to reduce redundancies from happening?

Tags: ruby, csv, parsing

I have a script that reads a CSV file that makes users for a Linux system. I have the code working and it does create the usernames, passwords, and the actual accounts for the system.

What I want to do, in the case that two people have the same name (unlikely but it happens) I want to add a number to the end of the duplicate user.

Example for CSV File:

first_name, last_name

john, smith

john, smith

Desired Usernames would be smithjn and smithjn1

Here is my code as is:

```
#Import CSV and io/console
require 'csv'
require 'io/console'

#Create Varaible for path to CSV File
filename = 'employeedata.csv'


#Start the Output File New Data
CSV.open("GeneratedUsers.csv", "w") do |outfile|
  # Headers for outfile
  outfile << ["First Name", "Last Name:", "Username:", "Password:"] 

  # Process Usernames, Passwords, and useradd command
  CSV.foreach(filename, headers: true) do |row|
        first_name_char = row['first_name'].strip.split('')
        useradd_name = "#{row['last_name']}#{first_name_char.first}#{first_name_char.last}"
        password = ""; 8.times{password << ((rand(2)==1?65:97) + rand(25)).chr}
        system("useradd '#{useradd_name}' -p '#{password}'")

    # Add new users and passwords to outfile
    outfile << [row['first_name'], row['last_name'], [useradd_name], [password]]
  end
end
```

Would I need to add a simple `if` statement to see if the username already exits and add a number if it does?

Comment: This is clear and well-written but you've asked two questions. You're more likely to get high-quality answers if you post two separate questions.